# AngularJS - scope conflict because of multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a conflict between my directive and the uib-datepicker-popup.
I´m getting a

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [input (module: myModule), uibDatepickerPopup (module: ui.bootstrap.datepicker)] asking for new/isolated scope

. Here´s my Code:

```
module.run(function($templateCache){
    if (!$templateCache.get('input.html')){
        $templateCache.put('input.html',
            '<div>' +
                '<span>' +
                    '<button type="button" ng-click="open = true">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>' +
                    '</button>' +
                '</span>' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TT.MM.JJJJ" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" is-open="open" />' +
            '</div>');
    }
});
```

and

```
module.directive('input', function ($interpolate, $templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,     
        controller: 'someController',
        compile: function (tElem, tAttr) {
            var content = angular.element($interpolate($templateCache.get('/input.html'))());
            var input = content.find('input');

            _.each(tAttr.$attr, function (attributeName, property) {
                input.attr(attributeName, tAttr[property]);
            }); 

            tElem.replaceWith(content);
        }
    };
});
```

In the view, it´s:

```
<input ng-model="myModel" uib-datepicker-popup></input>
```

The `uib-datepicker-popup` is causing the error. I guess it is creating its own scope, that is in conflict with the scope of the dierective. But I need the directives scope to be true. So what can I do?

Comment: *"But I need the directives scope to be true"* - Why? *"So what can I do?"* - Do not try to create multiple scope on the same element.

Comment: because of the `ng-click="open = true"`. If i have more thn one directive of <input> I don´t want all of the glyphicon-calendars to be opened, but just the one i clicked

Comment: Then create custom directive that would not create new scope but would set `uib-datepicker-popup` to inner input and recompile.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to add different datepicker-popups to different input-directives